# Lim Supremum fn(x) = sup f(x)

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We have a sequence of function converging uniformly to f(x) which is bound to [0;1]
I want to proove that the lim of the sup fn(x) = sup f(x) .

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The $x$ variable in the "second member", outside the suprema, does not refer to anything.

Comment: @Mindlack I was refering to the limit  function f(x) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists some $N \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$.

Thus, for each $n \geq N$, and each $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $\sup\,f_n - f(x) \geq f_n(x)-f(x) \geq -\epsilon$. In particular, $(\sup\,f_n) - (\sup\,f) \geq -\epsilon$.

You can get the other inequality in a similar way.

Comment: Can you explain me the " In particular " ? We have ‖−‖∞≤ .but how (sup)−(sup)≥− .?

Comment: Well, you know that for any $x$, $\sup\,f_n \geq f(x)-\epsilon$. Thus, for any $x$, $f(x) \leq \epsilon+\sup\,f_n$. As a consequence, $\sup\,f_n + \epsilon \geq \sup\,f$.